# How does vim know encoding of my files? When even I don't

Tags: vim, character-encoding

I have been in charset-hell for days and vim somehow always shows the right charset for my file when even I'm not sure what they are (I'm dealing with files with identical content encoded in both charsets, mixed together)

I can see from inspecting the ü (u-umlaut) character in UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-1 which encoding I'm in, but I don't understand how vim figured it out - in those character-sets only the 'special characters' really look any different

If there is some other recording of the encoding/charset information I would love to know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation can be found under `:help 'fileencodings'`:

> This is a list of character encodings considered when starting to edit
>     an existing file.  When a file is read, Vim tries to use the first
>     mentioned character encoding.  If an error is detected, the next one
>     in the list is tried.  When an encoding is found that works,
>     'fileencoding' is set to it.  If all fail, 'fileencoding' is set to
>     an empty string, which means the value of 'encoding' is used.

So, there's no magic involved. When there's a *Byte Order Mark* in the file, that's easy. Else, Vim tries some other common encodings (which you can influence with that option; e.g. Japanese people will probably include something like `sjis` if they frequently edit such encoded files).

---

If you want a more intelligent detection, there are plugins for that, e.g. [AutoFenc - Tries to automatically detect and set file encoding](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2721).